# How to mock or fake a CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, cancellation-token

I have the following method which I would like to unit test:

```
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ReadFileAsStream([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using (var reader = _readerWrapper.GetStreamReader("File.csv"))
        {
            await reader.ReadLineAsync();

            string? line;
            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }
```

I need a mock for CancellationToken, so that I can set up its ThrowIfCancellationRequested method to throw an exception. However, CancellationToken is a struct and I can not use Moq.

Does anyone have an idea how CancellationToken can be mocked?

Comment: Is there something stopping you from just using an actual CancellationToken and cancelling it before you call ReadFileAsStream?

Comment: Yes, I would like to write a unit test. Unit tests by definition should isolate all dependencies. If I use an actual CancellationToken and cancel it - then it will be an integration test.

Comment: @MiBuena, in my opinion you are being pointlessly dogmatic about this.  Should you try to figure out how to mock an `int` or a `DateTime` if your method has those as parameters?  Of course not -- that is not an "integration" test.

Comment: if you were talking about cancellation being the termination of a socket to an external service, then sure: that might be an integration test; here? no; that's still a unit test; either way: **does it matter what we call it?** (rhetorical: the answer I'm looking for here is "no"). The only important thing is that we *test the code*, which you can do just fine with a `CancellationTokenSource`

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't think you can or even should Mock the `CancellationToken` as it is a struct. This is like mocking `Int`.

One way you can test your logic is to create a `CancellationTokenSoure` and passing the delay parameter in the constructor and pass the token from the source to your method. After which asserting that the method behaves correctly.

i.e.

```
public interface IReaderWrapper
{
    public StreamReader GetStreamReader(string path);
}

public class Reader
{
    private readonly IReaderWrapper _readerWrapper;

    public Reader(IReaderWrapper readerWrapper)
    {
        _readerWrapper = readerWrapper;
    }

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ReadFileAsStream(
           [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using (var reader = _readerWrapper.GetStreamReader("File.csv"))
        {
            await reader.ReadLineAsync();

            string? line;
            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(OperationCanceledException))]
    public async Task ReadFileAsStream_CancellationTokenIsCnacelled_ShouldThrowCancellationException()
    {
        var mockedReader = new Mock<IReaderWrapper>();
        mockedReader
            .Setup(s => s.GetStreamReader(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(() =>
            {
                //Delay before returning
                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
                //return streamReader
            });
        // set delay time after which the CancellationToken will be canceled
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)); 

        var reader = new Reader(mockedReader.Object);

        // Should throw OperationCanceledException
        var result = reader.ReadFileAsStream(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

This way your the `_readWrapper.GetStreamReader()` will delay/wait longer that the set delay in the `CancellationTokenSource` and `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` will throw OperationCancelledException when it is invoked.

Comment: A string is a reference type thought, not a struct ;-)

Comment: Yeah I know. I just wanted to make a point :D I have edited the answer